# Android - How to manage multiples user levels and types

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-fragments

I have project  be used by different group then user.

For example: one group is secretary user, another is the admin user, medical user.

Currently my code this so below:

```
 if(App.getInstance().getCustomer().isAdmin())
        replaceFragment(R.id.view_main,new AdminFragment);
 if(App.getInstance().getCustomer().isMedical())
        replaceFragment(R.id.view_main,new MedicalFragment);
```

My question is, what is the way more sophisticated  to accomplish this control

Comment: basically, i want change layout dynamically according to the type of user of way more standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this sort of thing is done with a database. In websites you have different permission levels based on the type of user. A database can store information about users and when a user connects to the application, check what permissions they have.